# How can I easily add "." in array, can i do with slice?

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice

When I have array [a,b,c], I want to have output following example:

```
abc 
a.bc
ab.c
a.b.c
```

I tried with split and adding ., it doesn't give me what i want.

```
 var str = "vwxyzzyxwabcdefghijklmnopqrstu", 
 res = str.split(""),
 clone = "vwxyzzyxwabcdefghijklmnopqrstu";
 c = str.split("");
 i = 0; l = str.length;
 for (i = 0; i <= l; i++)
 { 
   var a = res.slice(i, l);
   r = c[i] + "."; 
   console.log (r + a);
 }
```

What will be easily and fast way to get results with.

Comment: Do you wish to print all possibilities of dot insertion into `"vwxyzzyxwabcdefghijklmnopqrstu"` to console? There are 536870912 of them. Are you sure you hate your browser that much?

Comment: Chrome browser can handle that much output I guess :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one idea of how to do it. I'm not going to do it on the string you proposed, though. :p

```js
function dotBetweenCharacters(str, callback, result) {
  if (str.length <= 1) {
    callback(result + str);
  } else {
    var base = (result || "") + str[0];
    var tail = str.substring(1);
    dotBetweenCharacters(tail, callback, base);
    dotBetweenCharacters(tail, callback, base + '.');
  }
}

dotBetweenCharacters("abcd", function(str) {
  console.log(str);
});
```

Answer:

```
abcd
abc.d
ab.cd
ab.c.d
a.bcd
a.bc.d
a.b.cd
a.b.c.d
```